# memcpy on malloc'ed memory is not running well

Tags: c, malloc, memcpy

I'm facing a really weird phenomenon of `memcpy`. I've allocated a data pointer with 2GB size, but it seems I can't do `memcpy` when my offset to the pointer is more than 1666800 bytes. Here is the code

```
dataMem = (struct dataRecord*) malloc(memsize * 1000000); // where memsize is 2000

... loop condition ...
{
    memcpy(dataMem + (dataCount * sizeof(struct dataRecord)), mesg, sizeof(struct dataRecord)); 
    dataCount++;
}
```

where `sizeof(struct dataRecord)` is 1200 bytes, and the `dataCount` is 1389. It supposed to be `dataMem + 1666800` and the offset still far from 2000000000, as allocated before.

I really confused about this and have no clue.

Comment: What processer/compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: Please don't cast the return value of malloc in C - it can hide subtle errors.

Comment: I use g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, Ubuntu 12.04 x64 3.2.0-23-generic, with 8GB RAM

Comment: should I declare the `dataMem` as `void *` and then `dataMem = malloc(size)` ?

Comment: So your OS is 32bit? I ask because you're asking to allocate approximately 1.907 gB of memory. How much is on the box is irrelevant  past 4gB, only 3 gB of which (at best) is addressable in a 32bit process. Are we to assume you actually *checked* the return value of that `malloc()` unlike the code above?

Comment: no, it's 64bit for sure. But the other case was that I cannot allocate more than 3 GB on this 64 bit OS. Yesterday I also search for the solution, but I think its OK for me to allocate only 2 GB for the process.

Comment: Is there a reason you're NOT using the size of your data record in the allocation computation? Just curious.

Comment: It's because I'm intended to use memory size parameters when executing my application. ex `./fva [memsize in MB]`. So I can prepare a mostly 2 GB memory to be inserted with bunch of data when triggered so. The data will be inserted using network.

Answer (score 0):

So I modified the code and get rid of the `malloc` casting.

```
void *dataMem;
dataMem = malloc(memsize * 1000000);
```

Seems the `memcpy` is working properly now. But why we must not cast `malloc`?

Comment: When using C (*not* C++, where it is required) casting `malloc()` can hide the difference between `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)`, and if they're not the same on your platform, bad things ensue. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc) for a better description. The better question is why your change 'fixed' anything.

Comment: [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).